# Exception handling with try

Tags: java, android

I'm using try and catch for handling exceptions.But when i use it says "Cannot resolve symbol" i'm using it in a class in a function but when i use it in activity no error occurs.

```
 public ArrayList<Earthquake> extractEarthquakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>()
{
    ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();

    try
    {
        //Capture and stores the root JSON object
        JSONObject rootJSONObject = ( JSONObject ) new JSONObject( SAMPLE_JASON_RESPONSE );

    }
    catch( JSONException e )
    {
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
    }

};
```

try and catch cannot be resolves.What should i do?

Comment: Cannot resolve which symbol specifically?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use an anonyomous class, extending `ArrayList<Earthquake>`? The problem ist most probably connected to my question. You use `try` and `catch` outside of a method (i.e. on class-level of the anonymous class).

Comment: Nope it is a normal class

Comment: @MruNiQue `ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>() { ... }` - this is an anonymous class, extending `ArrayList<Earthquake>`.

Comment: This seems like a bigger problem - you shouldn't be creating an anonymous class here in the first place. While it might seem like a nice workaround for Java's lack of collection initializers you are essentially creating an entire class simply for the purpose of adding to the list.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Try to put a ";" at the end of the first line: .. "xtractEarthquakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();". That should at least result in code the compiler accepts. Most like still not what you finally want but more likely to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a try-catch-block inside a function.
What you need to do, is to override the functions, you want to use the try-catch-block in.
Something like that:

```
public ArrayList<Earthquake> extractEarthquakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>() {
                //If you want to override e.g. the get-Function
                @Override
                public Earthquake get(int index) {
                    ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();
                    try {
                        //Capture and stores the root JSON object
                        JSONObject rootJSONObject = (JSONObject) new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JASON_RESPONSE);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
                    }
                    return super.get(index);
                }
            };
```